# Warning: require() [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

This error is quite common and it generally means it can't find the file it's looking for, but I can see the file in the directory?!

Full error:

> Warning: require(/home/coinsfut/public_html/files/core.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/coinsfut/public_html/new/index.php on line 4

line 4 says:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/files/core.php";
```

the site is hosting in `/new`

any ideas?

Comment: Did you output (echo) your path?

Comment: use web path relative to server-root like `files/core.php` instead of real server-path (or with beginning slash)

Comment: so 
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "files/core.php";    ?

Comment: Well, "No such file" means exactly what it says. You are using the wrong path. Output the required path and compare it to the actual path. Then fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the warning again. You are trying to include

```
/home/coinsfut/public_html/files/core.php
```

when in fact you want

```
/home/coinsfut/public_html/new/files/core.php
```

Please try

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/new/files/core.php";
```

and it should work just fine.

Alternative you could use

```
require "files/core.php";
```

to include files in a relative sub-directory since your index.php is in "new" directory.